# Ruby Benchmark module: meanings of "user", "system", and "real"?

Tags: ruby, performance, benchmarking

Experimenting with Ruby's Benchmark module...

```
>> Benchmark.bm(7) { |b| b.report('Report:') { s = '' ; 10000.times { s += 'a' } }  }
             user     system      total        real
Report:  0.150000   0.010000   0.160000 (  0.156361)
```

What are the meanings of "user", "system", and "real"?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

These are the same times that the Unix `time` command or other typical benchmarking tools would report:

- *user*: the amount of time spent executing userspace code (i.e.: your code),
- *system*: the amount of time spent executing kernel code and
- *real*: the "real" amount of time it took to execute the code (i.e. *system* + *user* + time spent waiting for I/O, network, disk, user input, etc.). Also known as "wallclock time".

Comment: @jorg Are the Ruby docs for Benchmark erroneous in that they show real times that are much shorter than total times? Source: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html

Comment: @rscott: user, system and total refer to the sum of time across all cores, whereas real is just the literal total time. Hence if code is running on a multi-core system, any of the first three can exceed the latter.

Comment: How about "total" then? I have a benchmark where "total" exceeds the sum of "user" + "system". How's that possible?

Answer (score -5):

Please check this gem:
https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/benchmark_methods

No more code like this:

```
t = Time.now
user.calculate_report
puts Time.now - t
```

Now you can do:

```
benchmark :calculate_report # in class
```

And just call your method

```
user.calculate_report
```